# Change cell Data on Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to take a template spreadsheet, and copy it, then change the data and export as pdf, finally email it.

So far I can do everything except change it on the sheet. It even changes in the logger. Can someone help with this?

Code as follows:

```
function After_Submit(e, values){
    var range = e.range;
    var row = range.getRow(); //get the row of newly added form data
    var sheet = range.getSheet(); //get the Sheet
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1,5).getValues().flat(); //get the header names from A-O
    var data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, headers.length).getValues(); //get the values of newly added form data + formulated values
    var values = {}; // create an object 
    for( var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++ ){
      values[headers[i]] = data[0][i]; //add elements to values object and use headers as key
    }
  
    
    const pdfFile = Create_PDF(values);
    sendEmail(e.namedValues['Your Email'][0],pdfFile);
  }
  
  function sendEmail(email,pdfFile,){
    
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Subject", "Message", {
      attachments: [pdfFile], 
      name: "From Someone"
  
    });
   
  }
 function Create_PDF(values, ) {
    const PDF_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1t_BYHO8CqmKxVIucap_LlE0MhslpT7BO");
    const TEMP_FOLDER = DriveApp.getFolderById("1TNeI1HaSwsloOI4KnIfybbWR4u753vVd");
    const PDF_Template = DriveApp.getFileById('1Ye7DyJQOjA3J_EUOQteWcuASBCfqlA-_lzyNw0REjY8');
    
    const newTempFile = PDF_Template.makeCopy(TEMP_FOLDER);
    const  openDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
    const newOpenDoc = openDoc.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var body = newOpenDoc.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (const key in values) {
    body = body.toString().replace("{{"+key+"}}", values[key]);
    }
    Logger.log(body);
    newOpenDoc.getDataRange().setValues(body);
  
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
    const BLOBPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    const pdfFile =  PDF_folder.createFile(BLOBPDF);
    console.log("The file has been created ");
    return pdfFile;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your script, in the for loop of the function `Create_PDF`, an array retrieved from the sheet is converted to a string. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.

When this issue was removed, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var body = newOpenDoc.getDataRange().getValues();
for (const key in values) {
body = body.toString().replace("{{"+key+"}}", values[key]);
}
```

#### To:

```
values = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(values).map(([k, v]) => [`{{${k}}}`, v]));
var body = newOpenDoc.getDataRange().getValues().map(r => r.map(c => values[c] || c));
```

- By this modification, the converted value by `values` are put into the sheet.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: All I can say is wow.. I worked on this for 10 hours and you solved my issue in seconds. I'm not even certain what some of that means. I would like to learn though. If you know any good App Script / Javascript courses please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: @Jml9548 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About my proposed modification, `values = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(values).map(([k, v]) => [`{{${k}}}`, v]));` converts your `values` by adding `{{` and `}}` to the key. By this, the value can be easily replaced. At `var body = newOpenDoc.getDataRange().getValues().map(r => r.map(c => values[c] || c));`, `newOpenDoc.getDataRange().getValues()` retrieves the values from sheet. At `.map(r => r.map(c => values[c] || c));`, each value is replaced using the converted `values`. By this, your goal is achieved.

Comment: @Jml9548 About more information on Google Apps Script, I think that this page might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info

Comment: Your answer has solved the issue. However now I am faced with one final issue. If there is a question left blank, like Question3 as an example. it still shows {{Question3}} after the template is populated. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Got it. After a few hours of figuring out the map function. I changed `values = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(values).map(([k, v]) => [{{${k}}}, v]));` to `values = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(values).map(([k, v]) => [`{{${k}}}`, `${v}`+" "]));` so it adds a blank space instead of the template holder. Not sure if this is regular practice but it works for me here.

Comment: @Zeekane I apologize for my late reply. From your comments, I'm glad your additional issue was resolved.